# Write formally: "$x$ is a prime number", 'if' or 'iff'

Tags: logic

I have to write "$x$ is a prime number" using logical symbols. I can think of two possible solutions:
$$a|x \Rightarrow a=1 \lor a = x$$
or
$$a|x \iff a = 1 \lor a = x$$
I cannot decide whether the right-to-left implication is necessary in this problem. Also, the first solution would be much easier to negate -thus allowing to produce an easy definition of "x is composite". 
Which one is better?

Comment: Both statements are equivalent, as $a=1\lor a=x \implies a\mid x$ is always true in $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 4):

The right to left implication is true regardless of the primality of $x$. The essential characteristic of prime numbers is captured with the first statement you wrote. You don't need the second.

Comment: This answer is making me wonder about the etymology of 'prime (number)' and 'primal' (primeval; fundamental), and whether one is derived from the other.